# mariadb - what wrong in this create function statement

Tags: function, mariadb

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_TP20avg (p_date date, p_symbol varchar(10)) RETURNS Decimal
BEGIN
DECLARE v_TP20avg Decimal(12,2);
SELECT avg(x.TypicalPrice) into v_TP20avg 
  FROM (SELECT TypicalPrice 
              FROM StockData 
             WHERE symbol = p_symbol
               AND PriceDate <= p_date
          ORDER BY PriceDate DESC LIMIT 20) x;
RETURN v_TP20avg;
END;
```

I am getting following error while trying to create function in MariaDB. I am not able to figure out what's wrong with syntax.

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

please help.

Comment: Use `DELIMITER`. [21.1 Defining Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

Comment: Thanks Anju.   this worked.      Delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION f_TP20avg (p_date date, p_symbol varchar(10)) RETURNS Decimal
BEGIN
DECLARE v_TP20avg Decimal(12,2);
SELECT avg(x.TypicalPrice) into v_TP20avg 
  FROM (SELECT TypicalPrice 
              FROM StockData 
             WHERE symbol = p_symbol
               AND PriceDate <= p_date
          ORDER BY PriceDate DESC LIMIT 20) x;
RETURN v_TP20avg;
END $$
Delimiter ;

Comment: For performance, I recommend `INDEX(symbol, PriceDate, TypicalPrice)`.

Comment: My select statement is filtering data using symbol and priceDate only. Do I need to include TypicalPrice as well in index?